# How to catch file mode?

Tags: c, fcntl

I have to catch modes below:

`"rb"`, `"r+b"` and `"wb"`.

I tried to execute code (compiled) of this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen("data.bin", "r");
    if (!file) {
        perror("");
        return -1;
    }

    int fd = fileno(file);
    if (fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) == O_RDONLY) {
        printf("read only\n");
    }

    // printf("%d\n", O_APPEND);

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

But gotten nothing printed. `fcntl()` returns integers like `32768`, but I need macros from the library like `O_RDONLY`.

Comment: You get 32768, which is `__O_LARGEFILE|O_RDONLY`

Comment: This sure seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What actual problem will having the raw file mode solve?  And not knowing what mode a file is opened in - by your own process - has a really nasty [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: it is not nasty code small if the intent is `assert( myfileisreadable( f ) )`.  it is there not for production code, but for testing code to help detect bugs.  this is the purpose of `assert`...

Comment: @ivoWelch That makes no sense.  Any read operation on a non-readable `FILE` stream would fail, and **that** would reveal any bug.  The check is extraneous, and as the answers both imply and explicitly state, the check can not be reliable.  How can not knowing what you're operating on *not* be a code smell?  "I've lost track of what I'm doing" is not just a nasty code smell, it's full-on rank, fetid, and downright poisonous.

Comment: you mean "I've lost track of what I am doing" is not a potential cause of bugs for memory constrained coders, that an extra assert during the debug stage could remind a future reader of the code?

Answer (score 5):

In general, you cannot catch -given a `FILE*` handle-, the file mode, in the `fopen` sense, with a portable C program.

For example, your `FILE*`  might be obtained with `popen`, `fmemopen`, `open_memstream`, `fdopen`,  etc... and could be writable only or readable only. It might not even have a valid file descriptor given by `fileno`.

You should *adopt* and *define and **document conventions*** about them.

For example, on Linux, a socket might be readable and writable at the OS level, and you could have two different `FILE*` handles on it (using `fdopen`) for the read and for the write sides.

And of course, a `FILE*` handle is not usable after an `fclose` (or a `pclose`)

So an hypothetical routine `fprint_stuff(FILE*, struct stuff_st*)`  should document that the first argument is a *writable* file handle, and would just call `fwrite` and `fprintf` but should check that these did not fail.

Comment: Maybe better to write function like `my_open(struct my_file*, const char *filename, const char *mode);` ?

Comment: Why? You want to take advantage of `FILE*`, but you need to document *conventions* about how you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Linux manual page `FOPEN(3)`

```
| fopen mode| open mode                 | 
|:---------:|:-------------------------:| 
|r          |`O_RDONLY`                 | 
|w          |`O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC` | 
|a          |`O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND`| 
|r+         |`O_RDWR`                   | 
|w+         |`O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC`   |  
|a+         |`O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND`  |
```

This code has been tested a bit, but I can't distinguish between r+ and w+ mode.

```
const char *get_fd_mode(FILE *source) {
 int raw_fd = fileno(source);
 int flags = fcntl(raw_fd, F_GETFL);
 if (flags & O_RDWR) {
     if (flags & O_APPEND) {
         return "a+";
     } else if (flags & O_CREAT || flags & O_TRUNC) {
         return "w+";
     }
     return "r+";
 } else if (flags & O_WRONLY) {
     if (flags & O_APPEND) {
         return "a";
     }
     return "w";
 }
// O_RDONLY equals 00, therefore flags & O_RDONLY gives us always 0
 return "r";
}
```